# Technical Term for Invisible Gap/Position

Tags: seo, ranking

I'm wondering if there is a associated technical term for describing the distance between rankings. For example if you have a site that is ranked 1st and another site ranked 2nd, the distance between the two can be either close, or miles away... e.g

[image: invisible seo gap]

What is the widely accepted term to describe the distance between rankings? if any at all...

Comment: I am finding this hard to understand exactly. You are clear enough, but the message is just not getting through. Is there a context you have in mind that can help??

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen such as gap.  The gap is usually uniform between the main 10 organic results. can you provide a link please.

Comment: Hehe, the gap isn't a visible thing... basically if your ranked second and your competitor is first... You could be very close to overtaking or very far, this is an invisible gap, the question is, is there a technical word used in the SEO world for this.

Comment: I think what you want to know is: how hard is it to overtake the next position in rankings? 


So, if all things are equal except for an unoptimized title tag (of course this would never be the case because we would have duplicate content but bear with me), this is a short distance to overtake the next best result. 

In contrast, if the 2nd result is severely unoptimized in all aspects, the distance or level of effort needed to optimize in order to overtake the next best position is that much greater. 


I understand your question I'm just not aware of such a term specifically for SEO.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no SEO name for such a distance.